# How to show co-ordinates of all points in a plot using pgfPlots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I'd like to show the co-ordinates of all the points which have been used for plotting a curve.
For this I have created individual nodes for all points manually, is there a better way to do this? I've gone through the documentation of tikz-pgf but I couldn't find a solution.

Here's the plot:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz,siunitx,float,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, positioning, calc, math}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}

            \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=left, thick, grid=both,
                    width=0.8\textwidth, height=0.8\textwidth,
                    xmin=0,xmax=110, ymin=0,ymax=150, y=0.06cm,
                    xlabel={Upper Limits}, ylabel={Cumulative Frequency}
                ]

                \addplot[color = black,smooth,very thick,mark=*,name path=h1] coordinates {
                    (10,3)(20,7)(30,19)(40,37)(50,57)(60,82)(70,94)(80,102)(90,108)(100,110)
                };

                
                \legend{Less-Than type Ogive Curve}
                \draw (10,3) node [above]{$(10,3)$};
                \draw (20,7) node [above]{$(20,7)$};
                \draw (30,19) node [above]{$(30,19)$};
                \draw (40,37) node [above]{$(40,37)$};
                \draw (50,57) node [above]{$(50,57)$};
                \draw (60,82) node [above]{$(60,82)$};
                \draw (70,94) node [right]{$(70,94)$};
                \draw (80,102) node [above]{$(80,102)$};
                \draw (90,108) node [below]{$(90,108)$};
                \draw (100,110) node [above]{$(100,110)$};
            \end{axis}
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Less-Than type Ogive Curve.}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to go through the `pgfplots` documentation, in particular look for `nodes near coords`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `nodes near coords` you obtain a plot very close to your desired result:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, positioning, calc, math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=left, thick, grid=both,
      width=0.8\textwidth, height=0.8\textwidth,
      xmin=0,xmax=110, ymin=0,ymax=150, y=0.06cm,
      xlabel={Upper Limits}, 
      ylabel={Cumulative Frequency},
      nodes near coords=,
    ]

    \addplot[color = black,smooth,very thick,mark=*,name path=h1, scatter] coordinates {
      (10,3)(20,7)(30,19)(40,37)(50,57)(60,82)(70,94)(80,102)(90,108)(100,110)
    };

    \legend{Less-Than type Ogive Curve}
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

You can customize thecontents of the nodes created with `nodes near coords` with an argument:

```
nodes near coords={
   $(\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}},
   \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}})$
},
```

where the keys `/data point/x` and `/data point/y` allow you to acces to data points, and the command `\pgfmathprintnumber` format the float number.

[image]